# Get blend of two colors in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have two colors in my .NET application that are user defined. I'd like to somehow get the color in between those two colors. It's the color in the middle of the gradient. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the *simplest* way is to take the average of each of the red, green, blue and alpha values:

```
Color c1 = ...;
Color c2 = ...;
Color midpoint = Color.FromArgb((c1.A + c2.A) / 2,
                                (c1.R + c2.R) / 2,
                                (c1.G + c2.G) / 2,
                                (c1.B + c2.B) / 2);
```

Even though the A, R, G and B properties are bytes, they'll be promoted to ints before addition, so there won't be an overflow problem. The result of the division will still be in the range [0, 255] and `FromArgb` takes `Int32` values but discards everything other than the lowest 8 bits - just what we want.

An alternative would be to use a different colour model (e.g. HSV) but that would be somewhat more complicated. For gradients, this should do fine.

Comment: That worked great. I also had to round to the nearest whole number or it would crash in some cases. Here is the VB code I ended up using:

MyColor = Color.FromArgb( _
Decimal.Round(((CInt(Color1.A) + CInt(Color2.A)) / 2)), _
Decimal.Round(((CInt(Color1.R) + CInt(Color2.R)) / 2)), _
Decimal.Round(((CInt(Color1.G) + CInt(Color2.G)) / 2)), _
Decimal.Round(((CInt(Color1.B) + CInt(Color2.B)) / 2)) _
)

Comment: You don't need to do all the decimal stuff - just use \ instead of / to make it use integer division. Do you have Option Strict turned Off? I wouldn't expect it to compile otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

Averaging is the best answer, but a word of caution:

An issue of color averages is that unless they're within the same thematic family, (high R, low G, low B) you'll end up trending towards grey.

Note that the more you use the averaging function, the more grey the result will become.

Answer (score 6):

By color do you mean an instance of `Color` struct?

If so, just take every of the `R`, `G` and `B` components in turn, and compute average for each. Combine the result to get your blended color.

Answer (score 2):

```
CByte((CInt(byte1) + CInt(byte2)) \ 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So was looking for a solution and decided to build off the avg idea to a general, kinda brute force lol, hope this help someone in the future.

```
// GetColors by Matt Meents, creates const foreach ARGB and then sum out the colors...
public static Color[] GetColors(Color A, Color B, int HowMany) {
  List<Color> aRet = new List<Color>();
  aRet.Add(A);
  if (HowMany > 0) {
    Int32 iCount = 0;        
    int sA = (B.A - A.A) / (HowMany + 1);
    int sR = (B.R - A.R) / (HowMany + 1);
    int sG = (B.G - A.G) / (HowMany + 1);
    int sB = (B.B - A.B) / (HowMany + 1);
    int AA = A.A; int AR = A.R; int AG = A.G; int AB = A.B;        
    while (iCount < HowMany) {
      AA += sA; AR += sR; AG += sG; AB += sB;
      if (AA > 255) AA = 255;  if (AA < 0) AA = 0;
      if (AR > 255) AR = 255;  if (AR < 0) AR = 0;
      if (AG > 255) AG = 255;  if (AG < 0) AG = 0;
      if (AB > 255) AB = 255;  if (AB < 0) AB = 0;
      aRet.Add(Color.FromArgb(AA, AR, AG, AB));
      iCount++;
    }
  }
  aRet.Add(B);
  return aRet.ToArray();
}
```